Primereact Menubar Displays Mobile Version on Refresh Before Switching to Desktop Version
I am using React with PrimeReact for my project. I've noticed an issue with the Menubar component where it briefly displays in the mobile version when I refresh the page before switching to the desktop version.
Here is an image captured right after refreshing the page:
Steps to Reproduce:
Load the page with the Menubar component.
Refresh the page.
Observe the Menubar display.
Problem:
Upon refreshing the page, the Menubar initially displays in the mobile version before quickly switching to the desktop version. I would like the Menubar to open directly in the desktop version without displaying the mobile version first.
What I Have Tried:
I have ensured that the window size is large enough to display the desktop version.
I have looked into the PrimeReact documentation but haven't found a solution.
enter image description here
How can I make the Menubar open directly in the desktop version without displaying the mobile version first? Are there any configurations or settings in PrimeReact that can help with this issue?
Thank you for your help!

Sounds like a hook issue. Like the menu renders then a hook sees that its mobile mode and re-renders it in mobile.    That to me sounds like it would explain the behavior.  Might want to look at the Menu source code and see how it switches to mobile mode.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ggkg4h?file=src%2FApp.jsx
it's the same code of primereact https://primereact.org/menubar/
Do multiple refresh and you will see that

Open a GitHub issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues
